# Comando para criar atalho de um site no smartphone?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Solicitar ao usuário que crie um ícone do meu site na tela inicial do seu smartphone.
Preciso que quando o usuário entrar no site ele receba uma notificação para criar o icone. Preciso saber o comando que faz isso. Já pesquisei e nada encontrei.

Comment: O que quer dizer com criar un ícone? Atalho ou ícone?

Comment: Pode ser feito sim, o que ele quer está aqui nesse site https://pushcrew.com o site pergu ta se o usuário deseja inserir um atalho na tela inicial e ao usuaruario aceitar o site faz isso sozinho.

Comment: Tem jeito sim, utilize o manifest.JSON Segue link com tutorial para implementação: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 2):

## Informar o utilizador

Para websites não existe tal comando, o controlo do que acontece no dispositivo está no utilizador do mesmo e não no que ele utiliza.

Deverás apresentar uma popup ou algo do género para informar o visitante que pode aceder ao menu X e adicionar um atalho à tela inicial.

```js
alert("Olá, adiciona-me ao teu homescreen fazendo uso do menu principal do teu navegador!");
```

Também podes ter um texto a detalhar como realizar a tarefa de forma a facilitar a vida ao utilizador:

> Como adicionar este website à tela inicial
>
> **iOS**
>   Clique no ícone que se parece com uma caixa com um salto seta fora dela (isso também permite que você tweet, imprimir ou enviar a página que você está). Clique em "Adicionar à tela inicial".
>
> **Android**
>   No Android há algumas maneiras diferentes de conseguir isso:
>
> - Adicionar o website aos favoritos
> - Vá para a tela inicial onde deseja adicionar o link / marcador
> - Tocar continuamente num espaço vazio até abrir o menu "Adicionar à tela inicial"
> - Selecione "Atalhos"
> - Selecione "Favoritos"
> - Escolha o marcador que você acabou de criar
>
> Dependendo do seu dispositivo e versão do Android, isso pode funcionar:
>
> - Adicionar o website aos favoritos
> - Abrir a gestão de favoritos
> - Tocar continuamente sobre o marcador do website
> - Selecionar "Adicionar à tela Início"

---

## Preparar a página com Icon, nome e cores a usar

Podes é ter a tua página com toda a informação necessária para dar a conhecer ao smartphone o icon e nome a utilizar no caso do utilizador adicionar o web site ao *homescreen*:

### Apple

[<sup>Link para documentação completa (Inglês)</sup>](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Meu Site"/>

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
```

### Microsoft

[<sup>Link para documentação completa (Inglês)</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```html
<meta name="application-name" content="Meu Site"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="http://www.example.com/windows_tile.png"/>
```

### Outros

```html
<title>Meu Site</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

---

**Nota:**
O concenso é os navegadores localizarem os icons identificativos das páginas web na raiz do domínio: `http://www.example.com/favicon.ico` mas podes especificar outras localizações fazendo uso das meta tags em cima.

Para gerar icons a partir de um só ficheiro, [esta ferramenta](http://iconifier.net/) é excelente.

Answer (score 0):

Desculpe, mas acho que não da via web.

As opções seriam:

- O usuário, utilizando os recursos do smartphone fará isso manualmente
- Você terá que criar um aplicativo nativo android que apenas abra seu site, terá um ícone e abrirá seu site como uma aplicativo, seria como se seu app fosse um 'navegador' (existe esse recurso) e abriria sua página web;
- Você utilizaria algum framework multiplataforma (exemplo phonegap) para criar esse 'app' para visualizar seu site;

Acredito que utilizando o Phonegap ou outra ferramenta multiplataforma (que usa javascript, html5, css e tal) seria mais prático, e não seria custoso (hardware do smartphone) pois só abriria sua página web (já que normalmente esse tipo de aplicativo é mais pesado). Além disso você poderia compilar o mesmo código para outras plataformas como windows phone, firefox os, ios, etc.

O nativo seria mais trabalhoso, porém mais leve (como já dito, pra proposta, não irá interferir no desempenho) e exclusivo para android.

http://phonegap.com/
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_plugins_pluginapis.md.html#Plugin%20APIs
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index